# Verbてform + くれるじゃないの Exact meaning

Tags: grammar, meaning

Correct me if I am wrong about くれる form. It means any action which we received from someone.

How does it change the meaning if じゃないの is added?

Example:

> 言ってくれる

> 言ってくれるじゃないの

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, I would like to make sure that the sentence you wanted to ask about is actually:

> 「言ってくれるじゃないの。」

as you wrote it, and ***not***:

> 「言ってくれる**ん**じゃないの。」

because those two sentences mean ***completely*** different things.

「言ってくれるじゃないの。」 is much more nuanced/complex than the words used might suggest.  I will talk about its grammar first, then its meaning and nuance.

「じゃない」 here is ***affirmative***.  It is not the negative 「じゃない」.

It is affirmative because the negative form of 「くれる」 will always be 「くれない」 and it will never be 「くれるじゃない」.  If someone said upon seeing my new shirt 「かっこいいじゃない！」, that would mean "That (shirt) looks great!"  The negative form of 「かっこいい」 is 「かっこよくない」 and never 「かっこいいじゃない」.

Sorry for the boring explanation, but I had to explain it because I have encountered quite a few Japanese-learners who did not know anything about the affirmative 「じゃない」.　"Quite a few" was actually an understatement.

Back to the sentence in question..

「言ってくれるじゃないの。」, therefore, means practically the same thing as 「言ってくれるね。」.

「言ってくれる」 here is nuanced as I stated above.  It is ***not*** the same as the "regular" 「言ってくれる」 that means someone tells you something (for your benefit).

***Here, 「言ってくれる」 means that someone has the guts to tell you something negative that others would probably hesitate to tell you***.

Thus, a sentence like 「言ってくれるじゃないの。」 is usually **uttered with a degree of sarcasm** in the speaker's tone.

> "Wow, you've got the guts to tell me that.  Thanks!"

is the nuance of the sentence in question.

Comment: It is very hard for Japanese learners to understand sarcasm from a native speaker. Is there any way to identify them in such cases?

Comment: @l'électeur would be great if you also give a short explanation about 「言ってくれるんじゃないの。」