# What does the phrase 「ナマ言ってくれるねぇ」 mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, slang

I'm not familiar with the term 「ナマ言って」 but I think it literally translates to "to say it raw" and くれる here can mean to give or receive it. So combining all that my guess is that 「ナマ言ってくれるねぇ」 translates to something like "you're telling it like it is"

Comment: The ～てくれる is NOT the normal "(someone) does something for me". For the usage of ～てくれる with sarcasm, used for a negative action: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/60960/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/938/9831

Answer (score 9):

Here 「ナマ」is short for「生意気{なまいき}」, meaning something to the effect of "impudent", "cocky". When you use「生意気｛なまいき｝」to describe the way someone talks or the stuff they say, you are saying they talk or behave in a very cocky or conceited way.

「くれる」, as you may know, is a marker that tells us the speaker is on the receiving end of an action. So this line means something like: "[They/she/he] say(s) some cheeky/impertinent stuff [to me]."

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that up, didn't know that 「ナマ」could be short for that